# MySQL group by day with TIMESTAMP column

Tags: php, mysql, database, group-by

I have a mysql table that has a column for "date time" in TIMESTAMP format.  Is there a way to group the rows by day using that column? And in an SQL query, not grouping them in php.

Comment: Do you mean it's in DATETIME format, or it's a VARCHAR with a date formated so?

Comment: It's type timestampt and default value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Hint: If it's a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column, the *format* that it displays is irrelevant. The time is stored in a numeric form internally, it's just formatted as `Y-m-d H:i:s` when you look at it.

Comment: (And how it's formatted when you look at it likely depends on your locale settings, too)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your column is one of the [Date and Time types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html):

```
SELECT ... GROUP BY DATE(`datetimecolumn`)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
GROUP BY TO_DAYS(`datetime_column`)
```

Comment: If the column is unixtime is possible use `TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME(\`unixtime_column\`))`. This works :D

Answer (score 3):

If you mean you have a standard DATETIME column, you can group by using one of the functions described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

For instance:

```
GROUP BY DATE(datetime_column);
```

If you actually have a TEXT or VARCHAR column (your answer doesn't specify), then you'll need to convert it to to a date first:

```
GROUP BY DATE(STR_TO_DATE(datetime_column));
```